# how to involve ggplot2 in a forloop?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, raster

I am using ggplot2 to plot some maps.
I confirmed the code is fine when not running in a loop.
However, when the variables are added to the loop, error shows up.
I would like to know do I misunderstand anything?
Thanks for any suggestion!
the error message is
`Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`
Here is my code for the for loop

````
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
####country shp
ammo_country=readOGR("/data/personal2/sun/ammo/gf/chelsa2_crop_selected/current/ammo_extent_country.shp")
ammo_country_df=broom::tidy(ammo_country,region="NAME_1")
cnames=aggregate(cbind(long,lat)~id,data=ammo_country_df,FUN=mean)
setwd("/data/personal2/sun/ammo/rona/")
variables <- c("Bio4", "Bio5", "Bio6", "Bio15", "Bio17")
scenarios <- c("ssp126", "ssp585")
time_periods <- c("2041_2070", "2071_2100")



for (variable in variables) {
  for (scenario in scenarios) {
    for (time_period in time_periods) {
      # Read rona.csv into R
      
      rona_data <- read.csv(paste0(scenario,"_",time_period,"_rona_xy.csv"),header=T,row.names = 1)
      rona_layer=raster(paste0(variable, "_",scenario,"_",time_period,"_diff.asc"))
      
      #range mask file
      range=st_read("/data/personal2/sun/ammo/gf/ammo_binary.shp")
      crop_layer2=crop(rona_layer,extent(range))
      crop_layer3=mask(crop_layer2,range)
      rona_df <- as.data.frame(as(crop_layer3, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"))
      
      # Plot the map
      a=ggplot() +
        geom_sf(data = range , color = "black", fill = NA, size = 0.7) +
        geom_raster(data = rona_df, aes(x = x, y = y,fill=paste0(variable, "_",scenario,"_",time_period,"_diff")), alpha = 1) +
        geom_point(data = rona_data, aes(x = x, y = y, size = variable), color = "navy", alpha = 1, shape = 21,  stroke = 1) +
        scale_fill_gradient(low = "lightblue", high = "blue", name = variable) +
        labs(title = variable)+
        scale_size_continuous(limits=c(0,0.6),breaks=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5))+
        theme_bw()+theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
        labs(title = variable, xlab = "Lon", ylab = "Lat", size = "RONA")
      a+geom_text(data=cnames,aes(x=long,y=lat,label=id),size=3)+geom_polygon(data=ammo_country,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),color="black",fill=NA)+theme_gray()
      ggsave(paste0(time_period, "_",scenario,"_",variable,"_RONA.pdf"),heigh=5.74,width=4)
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: This looks to be an [NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) issue.  More generally, your code runs and reports an issue with your data.  You've not shown us your data.

Comment: Hi, I found the error was occurred in this line `geom_raster(data = rona_df, aes(x = x, y = y,fill=paste0(variable, "_",scenario,"_",time_period,"_diff")), alpha = 1)` I am not sure if `paste0()` could be used as variable in `ggplot()`?

Comment: @Limey thank you for your link, I will read about it

Comment: `variable` is a character string. To make `ggplot2` recognize this string as the name of a column in your data you could wrap in the `.data` pronoun, i.e. try `size = .data[[variable]]`. And the same probably applies to `fill = paste0(variable, "_",scenario,"_",time_period,"_diff")`.

Comment: @stefan thank you for your suggestion! It works for me. I also found that `!!sym(paste0())` could solve the problem

Comment: Pei-Wei Sun, I marked this as a duplicate of the other question, recognizing that part of your problem was the error message. That is likely a duplicate as well, though I don't have the link handy ... if you got it to work, then great! If not, please [edit] your question to identify your changes and what (still) doesn't work, @-ping me, and we'll work through whatever doesn't work, possibly reopening the question. Good luck!